# multiple bolts in one topology using same stream

Tags: apache-storm

I've 1 spout and 3 bolts in a topology sharing a single stream declared originally using `declarer.declareStream(s1,...)` in the `declareOutputFields()` method of the spout.

The spout emits to the stream s1, and all downstream bolts also emit Values to the same stream s1. The bolts also declare the same stream s1 in their `declareOutputFields()`.

Is there any problem with that? What is the correct way to do it? Please provide sufficient references.

Comment: Streams are not global, they are local to a Bolt or Spout. Your bolts can emit on s1 as it is not the same stream as the one used by the spout. Also are you doing this because you want a loop of data in your bolts?

Comment: @zenbeni thanks for the clarification. No, I'm not using a loop of data. It is just a normal stream processing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your design, except it is unncessary unless you have a specific reason. According to Storm documentation:

> Saying declarer.shuffleGrouping("1") subscribes to the default stream
>   on component "1" and is equivalent to declarer.shuffleGrouping("1",
>   DEFAULT_STREAM_ID).

Thus if your bolts and spouts do not need to emit more than one stream, there is really no need to specify the steam ID yourself. You can just use the default stream ID.